# How to avoid writing same templates over and over?

Tags: c++, templates

Consider, for example, the following example, where we have two templated classes dependant on each other:

```
template <class T1, class T2, typename = typename std::enable_if<std::is_blah<T1>::value>::type, typename = typename std::enable_if<std::is_blah<T2>::value>::type>
class someClass
{
    // ...

    template <class U1, class U2, typename = typename std::enable_if<is_blah<U1>::value>::type, typename = typename std::enable_if<std::is_blah<U2>::value>::type>
    void fun1(U1 arg1, U2 arg2)
    {
        // ...
    }

    template <class U1, class U2, typename = typename std::enable_if<std::is_blah<U1>::value>::type, typename = typename std::enable_if<std::is_blah<U2>::value>::type>
    void fun2(U1 arg1, U2 arg2)
    {
        // ...
    }

    template <class U1, class U2, typename = typename std::enable_if<std::is_blah<U1>::value>::type, typename = typename std::enable_if<std::is_blah<U2>::value>::type>
    void fun3(U1 arg1, U2 arg2)
    {
        // ...
    }

    // ...
};
```

Right. In situations like the one described above I have to write the same template over and over. Needless to say this is ugly, makes the code unreadable, is tedious and troublesome, involves a lot of copy-pasting, etc, etc...

There simply must be a sane solution to this.

One, of course, is to #define this template. I don't think this is much of a problem since of course, I can #undef it as soon as I'm done with all declarations and definitions. But perhaps it is wrong; I'm just a greenhorn and I've seen people condemning any #defines.

Any other solutions? Or is this macro solution the best available one?

Comment: I'd rather go with `typedef` than `#define`.

Comment: @πάνταῥεῖ to be honest, I'm not really sure how to use a `typedef` here...

Comment: Well, you define it like `typedef T my_type` and you use it instead of `T`

Comment: @Ninetainedo I know that, but AFAIK I can't do `typedef template<...> my_template` and then write `my_template class C {}` or `my_template void f() {}`

Comment: @gaazkam I thought you wanted to avoid `sameOrVerySimilarLongAndComplicatedTemplate`? Why can't you say `typedef sameOrVerySimilarLongAndComplicatedTemplate T;`?

Comment: The goal is to replace `template <someLongAndComplicatedTemplate>` with `template <my_typedef>`.

Comment: `typedef` will only help when specifying the types, where the (poorly named) `templateParameters` is used as a placeholder in the code. I think the question is asking about how to avoid repeating the template parameter list; the bit in `template <typename T1, typename T2, typename T3=blah>`. These aren't types, they are template parameters, so a typedef won't help.

Comment: If the OP meant so, this question needs more details.

Comment: @Ninetainedo Yes, the question needs more detail, but I think that is obvious from the context in which the `someLongAndComplicatedTemplate` placeholder appears.

Comment: I didn't think so, even with the context. I thought there was big template usage involved. (Something like we can see in TMP, for instance)

Comment: Perhaps my question is confusing; well, sorry about that. You could substitute `template <someLongAndComplicatedTemplate>` with, for example, `template <class T1, class T2, typename  = typename std::enable_if<is_blah<T1>::value>::type, typename = typename std::enable_if<is_blah<T2>::value>::type>`

Comment: When you write `template <ZZZ> class A;` the `ZZZ` is not a type, it is a template parameter list. If `ZZZ` was a type, it would be `template<> class A<ZZZ>;`

Comment: @gaazkam thanks for confirming.

Comment: Thank you, OP. Now I see my answer was completely out of bounds. I don't see something nicer than a `#define`. I'm not really sure.

Comment: @gaazkam please edit your question to include the example you just gave in the comments. It will help to clarify what you mean. However, I can't see any alternative to just writing it out each time (I don't consider macros to be a good solution to this problem). You can help yourself by e.g. only having one `enable_if` and composing traits into a single trait class for selection. That should make it shorter, and have the side-effect of making your `enable_if` condition more reusable.

Comment: @Andrew Question edited. The problem with this solution is that if I any time decide to fix a bug the `enable_if` condition, I'll have to put the fixes everywhere... And I have problems with fitting in the 80 characters per line limit, so the template is a few lines long, which makes the code even more ugly. Could you very kindly elaborate a little bit more why don't you think macros are a good solution?

Comment: Your sample code still doesn't make sense. Default template arguments (which you are using for your SFINAE) isn't part of the signature and in fact can be specified only once.

Comment: @T.C. Thank you for pointing this out. Sorry for that. Should finally be correct now, I hope.

Answer (score 2):

The only solution I can see is to define some custom *type functions* and *aliases* that accomplish two goals:

- make your code more concise and (maybe) readable;
- make mantenance easier (i.e., as you pointed out in [your comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31743197/how-to-avoid-writing-same-templates-over-and-over#comment51421699_31743197), if you have to do a change, you will have to do in one place only)

For instance, you could change

```
template<typename T1, typename T2, typename = typename std::enable_if<std::is_pod<T1>::value>::type, typename = typename std::enable_if<std::is_pod<T2>::value>::type>
struct C1{};
```

in

```
template<typename T>
using Eif_pod = typename std::enable_if<std::is_pod<T>::value>::type;

template<class T1, class T2, class = Eif_pod<T1>, class = Eif_pod<T2>>
struct C2{};
```

Comment: That is nice, but I can't undo a `using`, can I... I mean, this `Eif_pod` thingy will be polluting every file that includes this file, and that's bad, since `Eif_pod` is nothing but a helper alias for `C1` and `C2`. That is why I was thinking about macros - i can `#undef` them as soon as I'm done with any stuff related to `C1` and `C2`. Or am I wrong, perhaps I really can undo a `using`?

Comment: I think this concern could be addressed by using a detail or anonymous namespace

Comment: @gaazkam C++ solution to scope pollution are namespaces. If C1 and C2 are closely related, they should be together into the same namespace, say C. On the other hand, something like Eif_pod is more general, so it could be in another namespace, say G. This way, if you think it makes sense, you could bring in scope all your G namespace into the C one, to make easier to use G's stuff into C. Sorry for the poor formatting but I'm using the smartphone.

Comment: OK, thanks. Could you also very kindly explain to me why the macro solution is wrong, because I don't think I get it?

Comment: @gaazkam The macro solution is not *wrong*. Though, macros don't obey C++'s scope and types rules, they are a mere substitution of some chars with others in your code. So, the compiler sees something different from what you do. This can lead to subtle bugs. See http://www.stroustrup.com/bs_faq2.html#macro